# Getting collation of SSAS cube with MDX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas, collation

Is there any way to get the [collation used by an SSAS cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/languages-and-collations-analysis-services) with an MDX query? I know it can be done with the T-SQL [`select DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('table','collation')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql), but I have an application that has only a OLEDB connection that I can send MDX queries to (so, no Server Management Studio).

I'm aware of [`OPENQUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql), but that requires a linked table, which I may or may not have, and I cannot create one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an MDX guru but don't think you can't use MDX for this. I have done this kind of thing using PowerShell and Analysis Management Objects (AMO). [This article](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3790066/Get-SSAS-Database-Properties-with-PowerShell-and-AMO.htm) is a a good reference. I can't test this but the Powershell cmdlett script will look like this:

```
PS C:\AMOScripts> $database.collation
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done indirectly by making a query that does some letter comparisons:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[IsAccentSensitive] AS 'a'<>'á'
            MEMBER[Measures].[IsCaseSensitive] AS 'a'<>'A'
            MEMBER[Measures].[IsBinary] AS 'A'<'_' AND '_'<'a'
         SELECT { [Measures].[IsAccentSensitive],[Measures].[IsCaseSensitive],[Measures].[IsBinary] } ON 0 FROM CubeName
```

IsBinary being true will trump IsAccentSensitive and IsCaseSensitive being true.
The binary test `'_'<'a'` is because '_' is between the upper and lower case letters in ASCII.